# Create an ASP.NET MVC Html helper similar to DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, mvc-editor-templates

In certain cases I want to display `SelectList` object not using `DropDownListFor` helper.  Instead, I want to create a helper that iterates over the SelectListItems, and draw something different.

**I have created an EditorTemplate:**

```
@model RadioButtonOptions

<div class=" switch-field noselect" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    @foreach (SelectListItem op in Model.Values.Items)
    {
        var idLabelF = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("") + "_" + op.Value;
        var esChecked = "";

        if (op.Selected)
        {
            esChecked = "checked";
        }

        <input type="radio" id="@idLabelF" name="@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))" value="@op.Value" @esChecked />
        <label for="@idLabelF" style="width: 100px;">@op.Text</label>

    }
</div>
```

**The `RadioButtonOptions` class is a ViewModel:**

```
public class RadioButtonOptions
    {
        public SelectList Values { get; set; }
    }
```

**The final resul looks like this:**

[image]

**My ViewModel is like this (simplified):**

```
public class MainVisitVM
{
    public MainVisit Visit { get; set; }

    public RadioButtonOptions VisitOptions { get; set; }
}
```

**And I use it in Razor View as:**

```
    <div class="clearfix">
        @Html.LabelFor(x=> x.Visit.Tipo)
        <div class="input">
            @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.VisitOptions ) //HERE
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem I have is that I want this to work more like the DropDownListFor, so the lamda expresion I pass is the property holding the selected value, and then just pass the SelectList object (or a custom list).

```
<div class="clearfix">
    @Html.LabelFor(x=> x.Visit.Tipo)
    <div class="input">
         @Html.CustomDropDownListFor(x=> x.Visit.Tipo, Model.VisitOptions ) //This would be ideal!!
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I think doing this using EditorTemplates will not be possible.
Any idea in how to accomplish this?

Comment: It is possible - by passing the list as `additionalViewData` and the getting it in the template using (say) `var List = ViewData["...."];`, but a `HtmlHelper` extension method would be better.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I will try the HtmlHelper extension method... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thanks to @`StephenMuecke` suggestion, I ended up with this `HtmlHelper` extension method:**

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonForSelectList<TModel, TProperty>(
           this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
           Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
           SelectList listOfValues)
        {

            string htmlFieldName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

            if (listOfValues == null) return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Empty);

            var wrapperDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
            wrapperDiv.AddCssClass("switch-field noselect");
            wrapperDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "padding-left: 0px;");

            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (SelectListItem item in listOfValues)
            {
                var idLabelF = htmlFieldName.Replace(".","_") + "_" + item.Value;

                var label = htmlHelper.Label(idLabelF, item.Text, new { style = "width: 100px;" }).ToHtmlString();
                var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, new { id = idLabelF }).ToHtmlString();

                sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", radio, label);
            }

            wrapperDiv.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(wrapperDiv.ToString());
        }
```

Not particulary proud of my `htmlFieldName.Replace(".","_")`, but works.

Comment: Note that `HtmlHelper` already contains a static method `GenerateIdFromName(string name)` but you could also generate the html as `<label><input type="radio" ...... /><span>yourText</span></label>` and use `var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, new { id = "" })` to remove the `id` unless you specifically need to for a css or javascript selector

Comment: Yeap, the id the radiobutton must match the FOR attribute in the label, in order to have the intended behavior. May be changing the markup as you pointed has the same final result. Thanks!